# Android app need to be built twice to avoid crash

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm facing an issue I don't understand at all. I have an Android app which will crash upon entering the settings (crash log below), but only the first time it is built. This issue was discovered while investigating why F-Droid builds were "faulty", while my own worked fine.

The steps to reproduce are the following:

1. `rm -r ~/.gradle`
2. ./gradlew assembleRelease && adb install -r ...

The build completes successfully here, but the APK does not work.

3. ./gradlew assembleRelease && adb install -r ...

The second build also completes, only this time the crash is not present anymore. Does anyone has any idea why such a problem could be happening?

The issue can be reproduced with the project located [here](https://github.com/JusticeRage/ApkTrack). The crash is triggered simply by entering the settings. Here is the full stack trace:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class PreferenceScreen
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItem(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.onCreateItem(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItemFromTag(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.addPreferencesFromResource(Unknown Source)
at fr.kwiatkowski.apktrack.ui.SettingsFragment.onCreatePreferences(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at fr.kwiatkowski.apktrack.ui.SettingsFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
... 29 more
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItem(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.onCreateItem(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItemFromTag(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.addPreferencesFromResource(Unknown Source)
at fr.kwiatkowski.apktrack.ui.SettingsFragment.onCreatePreferences(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at fr.kwiatkowski.apktrack.ui.SettingsFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For the sake of completeness, here is my Gradle information:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-01-03 15:31:04 UTC
Revision:     075893a3d0798c0c1f322899b41ceca82e4e134b

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11)
OS:           Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 amd64
```

I apologize for asking such a broad question. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "crash upon entering" "but only the first time it is built" but it works otherwise ? "I apologize for asking such a broad question" no, calm down you have been QUITE specific. ;O) (if enigmatic). Needs more  explanation. do you mean "run" instead of built ? I think you do, edit your question title.

Comment: No, I do mean built. The bug disappears if gradle is run a second time and the new APK is pushed to the device. Not a single line of code has to change.

Comment: Clean build comes to mind.Without that, any manner of bad things can happen. how reapeatable is this phenomenon?.

Comment: It' s a perfectly formatted and well asked question  (on firrst glance), but my first reaction is clean build it. Repeat it. Otherwise, join the club. I'm gussing Android Studio ? I should not have to guess. Edit your tags.

Comment: It's a feeling you get when you need to do a clean build (I almost never do a clean build), If you want me explain why I do not know. But you have to be able to REPEAT the problem, for it to be a valid question.

Comment: It's 100% repeteable: the problem manifests every time `.gradle` is deleted. No Android Studio needed: I build from the terminal using `./gradlew assembleRelease`.

Comment: You say: "the problem manifests every time", by your own admission it manifests (at least) every OTHER time ;O) . Does it occur after ./gradlew clean ? someone does not understand. Is it me ? Clearly a build problem.

Comment: The problem manifests every time you follow the steps described as 1, 2 and 3 in the original post. After 3, go to 1 to reproduce again. I'll try gradlew clean asap.

Comment: A `NoSuchMethodException` and a `release` build suggests a ProGuard issue. Try setting `minifyEnabled false` in `app/build.gradle` and see if the problem goes away. If it does, re-enable `minifyEnabled`, then work out a `-keep` rule to keep the methods from `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen` (and perhaps everything from `android.support.v7.preference`). As to why ProGuard would do different things on alternate builds... to paraphrase Churchill, ProGuard is a riddle wrapped in a mystery inside a warm flour tortilla and smothered in ranchero sauce.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this! I _think_ setting `minifyEnabled` to `false` did the trick! I'll confirm this and try to figure the right -keep rule!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CommonsWare suggested, the issue was resolved by disabling ProGuard for the release build. This confirms that it is the source of the problem, and work will now begin to figure out if a `-keep` option is missing somewhere.

Regarding the reason why two subsequent builds do not generate the same APK, I'm afraid I'll never know.